# Script name same as imported module name

Tags: python, module, pythonpath

If you have a script like:

```
import requests
requests.get()
```

and you name it `requests.py` you will get an attribute error saying that `requests` has no attribute `get` because Python is referring to the script name requests and that name doesn't have an attribute `get`.

However, if I have this script:

```
import time
time.sleep()
```

and I name it `time.py`, there won't be any error. Tried both on Python 2.7.11 and Python 3.5.3.

Why doesn't the same rule apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `time` is built-in, and request is a site package:

Try printing the `__file__` attribute to see where the module is located:

```
print(time.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

you get an error, but with `requests` you get the answer

```
print(requests.__file__)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py
```

another hint is given by `help(time.__loader__)`:

```
>>> help(time.__loader__)
Help on class BuiltinImporter in module importlib._bootstrap:

class BuiltinImporter(builtins.object)
 |  Meta path import for built-in modules.
```

for requests:

```
>>> help(requests.__loader__)
Help on SourceFileLoader in module importlib._bootstrap object:

class SourceFileLoader(FileLoader, SourceLoader)
 |  Concrete implementation of SourceLoader using the file system.
```

Anyway, *don't* call your modules as built-ins or library packages. In both cases you'll have problems.

- naming after a built-in: you cannot import it, as you saw
- naming after a site package: you cannot import the site package/use it in your module